# Text orientation inside node/HTML-like labels

Tags: graphviz

Is it possible to write vertically in a node/HTML-like label? (Rotating the text by 90, 180 and 270 degrees) If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Graphviz does not directly support rotated text.  However you can create external image files with rotated text (I used ImageMagick) and include them in your HTNL-like nodes.
Creating the images:

```
convert  -background lightblue -fill blue  -pointsize 72 label:'No\nParking' im.png; 
convert -rotate 90  im.png  im90.png;  convert -rotate 180  im.png  im180.png
```

Graphviz source:

```
graph i{
  t [shape=plaintext,label=<
  <TABLE CELLSPACING="2" CELLPADDING="2" BORDER="1">
  <TR>
    <TD><IMG SRC="image_dir/im.png" /></TD>
    <TD><IMG SRC="image_dir/im90.png" /></TD>
    <TD><IMG SRC="image_dir/im180.png" /></TD>
  </TR>
  </TABLE>
  >
  ]
}
```

Produces:
[image]